# ¿Cómo puedo transponer filas a columnas con PIVOT pero sin una función de agregado? o ¿COMO TRANSPONER FILAS SIN PIVOT? en sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql, pivot

Quiero pasar unos datos de filas a columnas, he intentado con pivot pero no me sale el resultado esperado, ¿hay alguna forma de hacer pivot sin función de agregado? o ¿Hay otra forma de transponer filas a columnas sin pivot?.

Esta es la tabla con sus datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y este es el resultado que espero:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradecería mucho la ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes resolver la situación utilizando la sentencia case.

```
Create table dbo.Datos (Terminal varchar(4), Name varchar(5), Valor varchar(20));
Go
Insert into dbo.Datos (Terminal, Name, Valor)
Values
('P001','CASA','ESQUINA'),
('P001','CARRO','CHEVROLET'),
('P001','FINCA','800'),
('P004','CASA','AL LADO'),
('P004','CASA','300'),
('P004','CARRO','200'),
('P002','CARRO','400');
GO
SELECT D.Terminal
    , CASE WHEN D.NAME = 'CASA' THEN VALOR END AS [CASA]
    , CASE WHEN D.NAME = 'CARRO' THEN VALOR END AS [CARRO]
    , CASE WHEN D.NAME = 'FINCA' THEN VALOR END AS [FINCA]
    FROM dbo.Datos D;
```

[image: Resultado]

Básicamente, si un valor de la columna name es igual al literal 'casa' entonces muestras valor.
Repites la misma sentencia para las 3 columnas y así obtienes lo esperado.

[Case When](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Muchas gracias, funcionó perfectamente!!